# Underscore.js templates break syntax highlighting in notepad++?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, notepad++

Here is a screenshot.  Is there an option I can set to fix this?

[image]

Comment: I found out, it is the JavaScript code in the template causing most of the disruption, just using simple template variables works, still need a fix on this though, maybe just put the JS in the JS.  Seems like it should be there any ways.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

This is a decent solution that makes me happy with the same problem.

Use Notepad++ User defined language dialog to import this xml document.

Then you should have a new option under language menu "JS Templates". I have the extension set as "phtml" you can change that and any other option in notepad's lang editor.

Probably don't have all the elements and properties though and some functionality is lost in this process and my colors are not too great.

```
<NotepadPlus>
<UserLang name="JS Template" ext="phtml" udlVersion="2.1">
    <Settings>
        <Global caseIgnored="no" allowFoldOfComments="no" foldCompact="no" forcePureLC="0" decimalSeparator="0" />
        <Prefix Keywords1="yes" Keywords2="no" Keywords3="no" Keywords4="no" Keywords5="no" Keywords6="no" Keywords7="no" Keywords8="no" />
    </Settings>
    <KeywordLists>
        <Keywords name="Comments">00 01 02 03&lt;!-- 04--&gt;</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, prefix1"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, prefix2"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, extras1"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, extras2"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, suffix1"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, suffix2"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Numbers, range"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Operators1">&gt; /&gt; &lt;script &lt;/script&gt; &lt;style &lt;/style&gt; &lt;span &lt;/span&gt; &lt;div &lt;/div&gt; &lt;ul &lt;/ul&gt; &lt;li &lt;/li&gt; &lt;h1 /h1&gt; &lt;h2 &lt;/h2&gt; &lt;h3 &lt;/h3&gt; &lt;h4 &lt;/h4&gt; &lt;h5 &lt;/h5&gt; &lt;hr &lt;br &lt;h6 &lt;/h6&gt; &lt;strong &lt;/strong&gt; &lt;a &lt;/a&gt; &lt;i &lt;/i&gt; &lt;p &lt;/p&gt; &lt;table &lt;/table&gt; &lt;thead &lt;/thead&gt; &lt;tbody &lt;/tbody&gt; &lt;tr &lt;/tr&gt; &lt;th &lt;/th&gt; &lt;td &lt;/td&gt; &lt;form &lt;/form&gt; &lt;label &lt;/label&gt; &lt;input &lt;select &lt;/select&gt; &lt;option &lt;/option&gt; &lt;button &lt;/button&gt; &lt;textarea &lt;/textarea&gt;</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Operators2"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code1, open">&lt;script</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code1, middle"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code1, close">&lt;/script&gt;</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code2, open"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code2, middle"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in code2, close"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in comment, open"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in comment, middle"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Folders in comment, close"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords1">id class href data- name required aria- value type placeholder tabindex src maxlength for enctype role method</Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords2"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords3"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords4"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords5"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords6"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords7"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Keywords8"></Keywords>
        <Keywords name="Delimiters">00&quot; 01 02&quot; 03 04 05 06&lt;?php 07 08?&gt; 09&lt;% 10 11%&gt; 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23</Keywords>
    </KeywordLists>
    <Styles>
        <WordsStyle name="DEFAULT" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="COMMENTS" fgColor="000000" bgColor="BBFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="LINE COMMENTS" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFF80" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="NUMBERS" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS1" fgColor="0000FF" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="1" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS2" fgColor="008000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS3" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS4" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS5" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS6" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS7" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="KEYWORDS8" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="OPERATORS" fgColor="800000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN CODE1" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN CODE2" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="FOLDER IN COMMENT" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS1" fgColor="FF0000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS2" fgColor="000000" bgColor="80FF80" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS3" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFCD9B" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS4" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFF80" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS5" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS6" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS7" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
        <WordsStyle name="DELIMITERS8" fgColor="000000" bgColor="FFFFFF" fontStyle="0" nesting="0" />
    </Styles>
</UserLang>
```